# Can two VSTO Add-ins handle the same outlook application event (application.newmailex)

Tags: vb.net, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm writing two add-ins for two separate departments that I work in. Both would process different types of email when they arrive, both are quite large add-ins though and I'd rather avoid merging the two. That being said, some people will eventually have to have both add-ins running at once.

Is it possible for two add-ins to be concurrently installed and for both of them to have subs that handle application.newmailex?

ie can I have:

Add-in 1:

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(EntryIDCollection As String) Handles Application.NewMailEx

    For Each itemID In Split(EntryIDCollection, ",")
        Dim item = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(itemID)
        If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
              if item.subject.contains("team1:") then
                   'do stuff
              end if
        end if
    next
end sub
```

Add-in 2:

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(EntryIDCollection As String) Handles Application.NewMailEx

    For Each itemID In Split(EntryIDCollection, ",")
        Dim item = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(itemID)
        If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
              if item.subject.contains("team2:") then
                   'do stuff
              end if
        end if
    next
end sub
```

Or do I have to maintain one big addin:

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(EntryIDCollection As String) Handles Application.NewMailEx

    For Each itemID In Split(EntryIDCollection, ",")
        Dim item = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(itemID)
        If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
              if item.subject.contains("team1:") then
                   'do stuff
              else if item.subject.contains("team2:") then
                   'do other stuff
              end if
        end if
    next
end sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, two different add-ins can be installed into same Outlook. Obviously they may have the same event handlers, there is no problem with that (you don't need to merge anything). The only thing which you cannot control is the order of notifications of those two add-ins. Your "Add-in 1" may get `Application_NewMailEx` first or second and same for your "Add-in 2". Just keep it in mind when coding.

Comment: Thanks, both handle very different conditions, so there should be no overlap.